# jQuery slow response to scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to make a resizing height navigation, as seen here: http://www.kriesi.at/themes/enfold/

I've gotten very close as seen here on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/magnusbrad/4DK3F/12/

```
<div id="nav" class="header">
nav here
<ul class="right">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
    $('#nav.header').animate({height:'140px'}, 500);
    $('ul.right').animate({'line-height':'140px'}, 500);
} else {
    $('#nav.header').animate({height:'40px'}, 500);
    $('ul.right').animate({'line-height':'40px'}, 500);
}
});
```

When you scroll down the animation works perfectly, however, when you scroll back to the top of the page it takes like 10 seconds to update and run the else statement. What am I missing to make that action happen faster, in real time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.animate()` adds to a queue each time it's called. So as you scroll away from the top, another animation is getting added to the animation queue for every scroll event. Then when you do get back to the top, the `.animate({height:'140px'}, 500)` animation is getting added to the end of the queue meaning it'll only occur once all the other animations have happened (each taking 500 milliseconds). Of course, you don't see these other animations taking place because you're telling jQuery to animate to the values that they already have, and therefore there's nothing visually happening.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Try:

```
var atTop = !$(document).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0 && !atTop) {

        $('#nav.header').animate({height:'140px'}, 500);
        $('ul.right').animate({'line-height':'140px'}, 500);

        atTop = true;

    } else if (atTop) {

        $('#nav.header').animate({height:'40px'}, 500);
        $('ul.right').animate({'line-height':'40px'}, 500);

        atTop = false;

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4DK3F/32/

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the fast reply. I appreciate the explanation on what's going on with .animate(). Can you quickly explain why you created a var first, and use the console.log?

Comment: @bradmagnus Oh, you can ignore the `console.log` - I was just using that whilst I was playing around with it. As for the `top` variable, I use that to keep track of whether the scroll position was previously at the top or not. That way I know if it needs to be animated.

Comment: @bradmagnus Also, looking at that site you linked to, I think the effect they have is actually closer to this: http://jsfiddle.net/4DK3F/29/

Comment: oh ya, I don't know why I didn't recognize the 'console.log'! I was just reading and comparing what I had previously... I think I get the 'var' then, it's being fed a new value any time the page changes position then correct?

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort on the the other fiddle! That's not currently what I'm looking for, for the site I'm working on currently, but very handy! I'll keep that bookmarked for sure.

Comment: @bradmagnus well `var` is just used to declare a new variable. And that variable, `top`, is set to `true` whenever someone scrolls back to the top of the page; and to `false` whenever someone scrolls away from the top. Therefore, by using `top` and looking at `$(document).scrollTop()` we can determine if the scroll event handler actually needs to do anything constructive.

Comment: Ok, @BYossarian, you've been amazingly helpful! But I've now run into a problem, when I actually try to implement into my wp theme, it's not working right. If you could look at this, I'd really appreciate it: http://ec2-54-226-59-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com/wordpress/

It's temp server, only good for about 50 more minutes.

Comment: @bradmagnus if you're still having issues gimme a shout

Comment: yes I am still having the issue! I've uploaded it to my site, [link](dev.bradmagnusdesign.com). It's strange, because it's only resizing the container div on the initial scroll down the page, but not when returning to top, and it's ignoring the 2 other statements as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @bradmagnus ah, I'd been a bit thoughtless with my variable naming. I've changed it, and wrapped it in a closure to prevent any other possible conflicts: http://jsfiddle.net/4DK3F/34/

Comment: you totally saved my bacon on this site! Thank you so much for keeping up with it and helping me get it implemented correctly! I updated the above link to my dev subdomain to reflect the changes!