# jQuery conflict in div resizing or something?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I got some awesome help yesterday trying to figure out how to create a resizing navigation bar: [jQuery slow response to scrollTop()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483736/jquery-slow-response-to-scrolltop) However, when I implemented it into the WP Theme, it's not working right at all! The container div resizes properly when you scroll down the page, but nothing happens when scroll back to the top of the page. I'm using Zurb Foundation Framework, Reverie theme dev server here: http://dev.bradmagnus.server287.com/

I'm in pretty desperate need of some help! I've spent far too long on trying to get this navigation figured out. I really appreciate your help and this awesome community on stackoverflow!

Here's the fiddle where it's working perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/magnusbrad/pRgNc/8/

And here's the jQuery in question:

```
var top = !$(document).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0 && !top) {

        $('div#navigation.fixed').stop().animate({'height':'140px'}, 300);
        $('.title-area img').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-198-67-10.jpg');

        $('ul.right').animate({'margin-top':'0'}, 300);

        top = true;

    } else if (top) {

        $('div#navigation.fixed').animate({'height':'40px'}, 300);
        $('.title-area img').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-198-67-6.jpg');
        $('ul.right').animate({'margin-top':'-50px'}, 300);

        top = false;

    }
});
```

Comment: "It's not working right at all!" isn't much to go on. Please be more descriptive about the actual issue. Treat each question as separate and don't assume prior knowledge about your scenario.

Comment: I wish I could be more descriptive @ChrisP, but I'm not very familiar with jQuery enough to actually debug the issue. That's why I linked to the site in question. I updated the question above, hope that's enough to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather a funny one :). Here's the Problem:

By using the `$(window).scroll(function () {}` function, you trigger the event "every time" you scroll. So if you scroll down the whole page your event is getting triggeded about 50 times. Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZnsJ/) fiddle, I have simply replaced the log function with an alert to make this error visible.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I guess its the reason because it doesnt work: You have set 300ms animation time to each trigger which will change the duration of ur animation to about 10-20 seconds if it gets triggeret multiple times. Have you seen that the navigation on your site reapperes after some time if you stop scrolling and just wait?

I suggest you trigger the resizing event, which shrinks your menu, only once. the other scroll events which get triggered can skip this event because it only needs to get resized once. Then, when the user has finished scrolling, i would just check if the user is on top of the page. If yes, change the size of the menu back to the original size.
All of that together you can find in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RRHtW/) fiddle.

To make you animation complete you just need to set more css into your jquery action. Right now, you are just executing 
`$('div#navigation.fixed').stop().animate({'height':'140px'}, 300);`
but to display the menu you need also to edit the css of the `<ul class="right">` otherwise they are not visible because the wrapper gets shrinked.

Give it a try and let me know if it helped.